# How to wrap cover div inside reactjs fragments dynamically

Tags: html, reactjs, jsx

I am trying to wrap html around inner div only when some condition is met.  But when I run the script, it says Module build failed: SyntaxError  Unexpected token. I tried to use conditional rendering.

```
return (
    <Fragment>
        <div>
            {
                (true) ? <div class="imghvr-wrapper"> : ''
            }
            <div class="imghvr">
                <div class="imghvr-overlay imghvr-anim-none imghvr-anim-single">
            </div>
            {
                (true) ? </div> : ''
            }
        </div>
    </Fragment>
);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Like this:

```
const myComponent = () => {
    const myCondition = true;
    const child = (
        <div className="imghvr">
            <div className="imghvr-overlay imghvr-anim-none imghvr-anim-single" />
        </div>
    );
    return (
        myCondition ? <div className="imghvr-wrapper">{ child }</div> : child
    );
};
```

You can't split tags like this: `myCondition ? <div className="imghvr-wrapper"> : null` you should always close your tags. For example that code is valid: `(true) ? <div className="imghvr-wrapper"/> : ''` because tag is closed